# How to access two different XML files with jQuery Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have two functions

```
function ShowCrossWord(var randN)
{
     randomnumber = randN;

     $(document).ready(function() {
       $.get("crosswords.xml",{},function(xml){
         $('crossword',xml).each(function(i) {  });
       });
     });
}
```

and

```
  function ShowLegend(var randN)
  {
    randomnumber = randN;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.get("legends.xml",{},function(xml){         
            $('legend',xml).each(function(i) {});
      });

    });
  }
```

I am using these in a same javascript file:

```
   var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*233);   
   ShowCrossWord(randomNumber);
   ShowLegend(randomNumber);
```

None of them seems to work.
What would be the solution.

Comment: what's the response you get from the server?  Check your firebug net log or web inspector to see where the request goes and what the response is.  There are SO many reasons why this could be failing, we need more information.  It also appears that your random number has nothing to do with this q, you can leave it out for brevity, and also, these two functions do the same thing, i'm sure you can combine them into one and pass in the url of interest to query with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What were you expecting to happen, and what actually happened?

So things I can see:

- You never do anything with the XML data. I presume it is not even being returned?
- You may need to specify a [dataType attribute](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) of "xml" so jQuery knows what type of data the server is returning.

I recommend you double-check these points above, and then use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to further narrow-down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your mimetype of the XML sent from the server is wrong. It's very picky to get that right, or the XML will not be parsed on the client.

You could try to register callback functions for success and error and log the error message and the XMLHTTPRequest object.